# Save the multiple disabled button to the local storage

Tags: javascript

my target is to save my disabled state even though I'm refreshing the webpage. Currently I can only save 1 data to my local storage (Please see the image link). My target is how can I save multiple button disabled state in my `localstorage`? Thank you

http://prntscr.com/1dc78u1

html:

```
<button type="button" id ='button1'> Button 1 </button> 
<button type="button" id ='button2' disabled > Button 2 </button>
<button type="button" id ='button3' disabled > Button 3 </button>
```

script:

```
var disbledBtn = localStorage.getItem('disabled'); // get the id from localStorage
$(disbledBtn).attr("disabled", true); // set the attribute by the id

$('#button1').click(function () {
  $("#button1").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#button2").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#button3").attr("disabled", false);
  localStorage.setItem('disabled', '#button2'); // store the id in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('disabled', '#button3');



});
```

Comment: You are closing button tag wrong:
```html
<button type="button" id ='button1'> Button 1 </button> 
<button type="button" id ='button2' disabled > Button 2 </button>
<button type="button" id ='button3' disabled > Button 3 </button>
```

Comment: I edited it now. But it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save array in `localStorage`. But note that your `localStorage` key  must be unique, otherwise you miss previous value with the same key.

And you can use `disbledBtn.split(",")` to split the each button `id`.

Try this one:

```
var disbledBtn = localStorage.getItem('disabled');// get the id from localStorage

if (disbledBtn)
    disbledBtn.split(",").forEach((t) => { $(t).attr("disabled", true); })


$('#button1').click(function () {
    $("#button1").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#button2").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#button3").attr("disabled", false);
    localStorage.setItem('disabled', ['#button2', '#button3' ]); // store the id in localStorage
});

<button type="button" id='button1'> Button 1 </button>
<button type="button" id='button2'> Button 2 </button>
<button type="button" id='button3'> Button 3 </button>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I applied your suggestion and i got this error
http://prntscr.com/1dd0h2e  

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Comment: I updated my answer.  Put `if (disbledBtn)` before split

Comment: I got this error. http://prntscr.com/1ddjgpg 

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.html:13

Comment: You need to add jquery reference!
add this into `head` tag
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Based on your code I give you jquery solution

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. Appreciated you and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store multiple values in one item.

Read this [freecodecamp Web Storage Doc](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-store-data-in-web-browser-storage-localstorage-and-session-storage-explained/) to find how you can do this.